# npm ERR! fsevents not accessible from rollup

Tags: npm, rollupjs, fsevents

I am trying to build my Angular app on Gitlab CI, and install the dependencies with `npm ci`, but I encounter an error '**fsevents not accessible from rollup**'. I tried `npm ci --no-optional` and still having this error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have also got the same error with `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.14"`. I have resolved this issue by upgrading npm from ver6 to ver7 with node ver 14

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 0):

updated my angular 11 project dev dependencies to:

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.13",
```

needed to install webpack and here we go..